# Set all Jquery UI accordion to start open when loading the application

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following accordion code:

```
(document).ready(function() {
  $("> div", "#questionsDispos").draggable({
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid",
      cursor: "move",
      handle: "h3",
      connectToSortable: ".questions"
  });

  $(".emitters").accordion({
      header: "> div > h3",
      collapsible: true,
      active: false,
      autoHeight: false,
      autoActivate: true,
      animate: {
          duration: 200
      }
  });

  $(".emitters").sortable({
      axis: "y",
      handle: "h3",
      items: "div",
      receive: function (event, ui) {
          $(ui.item).removeClass();
          $(ui.item).removeAttr("style");
          $(".questions").accordion("add", "<div>" + ui.item.hmtl() + "</div>");
      }
  });

  $("#questionsDispos").accordion({
      header: "> div > h3",
      collapsible: true,
      active: true,
      autoHeight: false
  });

  $('#accordion').accordion({
      collapsible:true,
      beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
          // The accordion believes a panel is being opened
          if (ui.newHeader[0]) {
              var currHeader  = ui.newHeader;
              var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
              // The accordion believes a panel is being closed
          } else {
              var currHeader  = ui.oldHeader;
              var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
          }
          // Since we've changed the default behavior, this detects the actual status
          var isPanelSelected = currHeader.attr('aria-selected') == 'true';

          // Toggle the panel's header
          currHeader.toggleClass('ui-corner-all',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top',!isPanelSelected).attr('aria-selected',((!isPanelSelected).toString()));

          // Toggle the panel's icon
          currHeader.children('.ui-icon').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s',!isPanelSelected);

          // Toggle the panel's content
          currContent.toggleClass('accordion-content-active',!isPanelSelected)
          if (isPanelSelected) { currContent.slideUp({animate: {duration: 200}})}
          else { currContent.slideDown({animate: {duration: 200}}); }

          return false; // Cancels the default action
      }
  });
});
```

And I need to have it open by default, then the user can choose whether to close or not. I add those dynamically base on web socket information and I need to get it to auto open when I add them.

How can I set it?

Comment: Btw, it seems like a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248276/jquery-accordion-open-item-on-page-load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi refre this link https://plnkr.co/edit/MgSzjrcC08fR4xCgHyIG?p=preview

CODE

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(function() {
            $("#accordion > div").accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible: true });
        })
    })(jQuery);
</script>

<div id="accordion">
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
        <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
        <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

u have to specify each accordion inside div

Comment: I am exactly as you specified.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was what I need.

Comment: happy coding @ksup

Answer (score -1):

Add `active : true` to your accordion

```
$("#accordion").accordion({  active: false });
```

Comment: I set my active to true, and now only the first accordion section is starting open and the rest are closed.

Comment: @ksup You need to check your console if there are any errors. 
And all these people who have answered here, won't be wrong just because it didn't work for you. So stop downvoting every answer.